# Gitlab-ci file has no effect on my project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to auto-build/deploy my angular app to my remote server but I don't get why the `gitlab-ci.yml` is not working :

```
image: trion/ng-cli-karma

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq sshpass

deploy_stage:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Staging
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - rm ./package-lock.json
    - npm install
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --progress false --single-run=true --watch=false
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng e2e --progress false --watch=false
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --progress false --prod
    - cd dist/
    - ls
    - sshpass -V
    - export SSHPASS=$USER_PASS
    - sshpass -e scp -o stricthostkeychecking=no -r . myusername@myserver:/var/www/html


deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Production
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - rm ./package-lock.json
    - npm install
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --progress false --single-run=true  --watch=false
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng e2e --progress false --watch=false
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --progress false --prod
    - cd dist/
    - ls
    - sshpass -V
    - export SSHPASS=$USER_PASS
    - sshpass -e scp -o stricthostkeychecking=no -r . myusername@myserver-prd:/var/www/html
```

On my Gitlab CE server, I don't see the effect of the file, there is no build job :

[image]

Am I missing a step here?

Comment: Can you make a very simple .gitlab-ci.yml file just to see if that works? Just one job, with `stage: build` and `script: echo test`, or something like that. Then you can work up from there and see where your script stops working. It might be that you have done this new .gitlab-ci.yml file on a branch, but you use `only: master`, so it won't be run until you merge it. The other job is only run on tags, because of the `only: tags`. Ignore what I wrote before about `stage` in GitLab. `build`, `test`, `deploy` are the default ones.

Comment: @Rekovni indeed the problem was with the naming. thanks for your help. please answer the question so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gitlab-ci.yml` file you mentioned in your question should be renamed to `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

[GitLab CI/CD Pipeline Configuration Reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/)
.